# Reading XML from Goodreads API and getting specific elements from it

Tags: c#, rest, .net-core

Goodreads API has a GET request as follows:

> Paginate an author's books.
>
> Get an xml response with a paginated list of an authors books.
>
> URL: https://www.goodreads.com/author/list.xml    (sample url)
>
> HTTP method: GET
>
> Parameters:
>
> key: Developer key (required).
>
> id: Goodreads Author id (required)
>
> page: 1-N (default 1)

I have my devkey in my API Controller:

```
private readonly string devkey = "(my private dev key here)";
```

I have a GetBook method as follows:

```
[HttpGet("{id}")]
public async Task<string> GetBook(string id)
{
    WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
    webClient.QueryString.Add("key", devkey);
    webClient.QueryString.Add("id", id);
    string result = await webClient.DownloadStringTaskAsync("https://www.goodreads.com/author/list.xml");

    return result;
}
```

The id parameter is the id of the author according to the authors goodreads ID.

This method successfully returns me the XML response of the authors work. What I want to do is only select specific elements from the XML and return it as a list, say, a list of the titles of the books, or the number of pages, etc. What is the best way to accomplish this, and can I improve my original method? This is only an API solution but I want to connect it with an MVC project when I get it working so I can also assign those values to my own data objects and display them in views.

Comment: There are many ways of parsing xml file in Net Library.  The best method depends on the size of the xml file, the amount of data you need to retrieve, and the structure of the xml.  without seeing a sample of the xml it is difficult to give a BEST method.  In most cases I usually prefer using the xml linq net library.

Comment: @jdweng The XML response is 1300+ lines, I've pasted an example response here: https://pastebin.com/Yc6KH0ex

Answer (score 0):

Try using Linq with a Dictionary.  See code below.  I just group items.  Did not return specific value.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.IO;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string xml = File.ReadAllText(FILENAME);

            XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(xml);

            string key = "title";  //tag to sort by

            Dictionary<string, XElement> dict = doc.Descendants("book")
                .GroupBy(x => (string)x.Element(key), y => y)
                .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, y => y.FirstOrDefault());
        }
    }
}
```

---

For huge XMl files use following :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string URL = "MyURL";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(URL);
            Dictionary<string, XElement> dict = new Dictionary<string, XElement>();
            while (!reader.EOF)
            {
                if (reader.Name != "book")
                {
                    reader.ReadToFollowing("book");
                }
                if (!reader.EOF)
                {
                    XElement book = (XElement)XElement.ReadFrom(reader);
                    string title = (string)book.Element("title");
                    dict.Add(title, book);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried this but I get "The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect". I've gotten a few different errors that hints to the file not being correctly formatted or labelled but I'm not sure how to debug that

Comment: Use the string returned from response.  If you read a file instead use XDocument.Load(filename).  I used code from the pastebin in the raw view at bottom of page.

Comment: I am using the string returned, there is nothing else to use. It's simply too large and I can't find anything that tells me how to handle it. Now I'm getting a "Invalid URI: the uri sring is too long."

Comment: Huge Xml files you have to use XmlReader.  I will post sample.